# Override sql database field values while filling a report in Jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, sqlconnection

I've the following code to fill a report in JasperReports by passing some parameters and a postgresql database connection:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, jasperFillManagerParameters, sqlConnection);
```

The database is a third-party DB and I can't make any change on it, I also can't change report template (`jrxml` file); But I need to modify values of some fields while filling the report (e.g. some date convertions), so the only place I can make my changes is when I fill the report using above code.
I know that I need to work with `JasperFillManager` (e.g. override some of its aspects) to achieve this goal, but I don't know how should I exactly do this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of the JasperFillManager why not work with the JasperPrint object?, If you know where to find the stuff in the JasperPrint, you can set/remove move them as you like.... but question like this seems a bit broad....

Comment: @PetterFriberg my report is building dynamically, I mean number, name and content of columns are not fixed. I just apply some rules on column names to identify which column values should be edited.